# ¿Hay alguna forma de configurar Python para que detecte todos los errores sin tener que ejecutar el script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me gustaría saber si es posible configurar Python para que avise de todos los errores sin tener que ejecutar el script. Ya sé que al principio de la ejecución hace un análisis sintáctico. Pero creo que no es suficiente.

Me refiero a que también avise de los errores léxicos, de dependencias y ese tipo de cosas.

Bueno, cuando tienes un scritp pequeño tal vez no te importa porque la ejecución dura poco, pero cuando llevas 10 minutos de ejecución y de repente te sale un error como este, te dan ganas de tirarte de los pelos.

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Porque ahora lo corrijo y tengo que esperar 10 minutos mas para que llegue al mismo punto y tocar madera para que no salga otro error y tener que empezar desde el príncipio. Yo lo veo así, 6 errores = una hora perdida de mi vida.

Pues eso, sería estupendo que se pudiera configurar para trabaje de esa forma, igual que lo hacen los compiladores de C/C++ y otros lenguajes no interpretados.

Si se puede hacer por favor diganme cómo. 
Gracias!!

Comment: En un lenguaje interpretado(semi-interpretado) como python sera dificil, yo diria imposible hacerlo ya que python permite la creacion de propiedades dinamicamente, por ejemplo mire el siguiente codigo: `obj = SomClass()` `obj.some_property = 4` `obj.some_property += 1` `obj.some_property = "Hola mundo"`, ¿como se podria verificar que la suma con un entero esta definido?

Comment: Es por eso que se recomienda el desarrollo en base a pequeñas funciones específicas y el uso de *unit tests*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero "todos los errores sin tener que ejecutar" es un poco complicado, incluso C y C++ los cuales mencionas tienen errores en tiempo de ejecución y que al ser compilados no son tan explícitos e informativos como los que el intérprete Python te muestra.

Ahora bien, en el error que muestras yo señalaría dos aspectos de Python que que debemos tener en cuenta, la primera es que en Python se **pueden añadir atributos o métodos en tiempo de ejecución** a una clase o un objeto, por lo que va a ser difícil para un analizador estático saber si el objeto tiene o no ese método en un momento dado. Para lo bueno y para lo malo Python permite hacer cosas que no permite C++ u otros lenguajes compilados.

La segunda es el tipado dinámico, estrictamente en Python no existe el concepto de "tipo de variable" al uso de C, en Python las "variables" son nombres que se asocian a un objeto en memoria (un `int` es un objeto) y que se pueden en un momento dado asignar a otro objeto sin problemas.

En Python 3  partiendo de  [PEP 483 -- The Theory of Type Hints](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) y con la implementación de las [anotaciones](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) se ha introduciendo la posibilidad de especificar el tipo de de una variable/atributo así como el retorno  y argumentos de una función/método.

No hay que confundirse, **Python sigue siendo por ahora estrictamente un lenguaje dinámicamente tipado y el intérprete no realiza ninguna comprobación de tipos por si solo**, pero lo anterior permite indicar al buen lector de nuestro código y a herramientas diseñadas para la comprobación de tipos que tipo se espera que tenga nuestra variable o retorne nuestra función, permitiendo una comprobación de tipos previa a la generación del bytecode y su ejecución.

Hay IDEs como PyCharm que tienen su propio comprobador de tipos, mostrándote la advertencia en el propio editor, además basándose en todo lo anterior tenemos el [proyecto MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) inicialmente desarrollado por DropBox y alojado en el mismo repositorio que Python actualmente, que permite la comprobación de tipos estáticos en Python, un pequeño ejemplo:

```
class Button:
    def click(self):
        print("Click")

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.btn= Button()


app = App()
app.btn.click() # Todo bien

app.btn = []    # Upsss!!!
app.btn.click()
```

El problema del código simple anterior, que es posiblemente similar al problema que generó tu error, es que el atributo `btn` debe ser una instancia de `Button`, no cualquier otra cosa como una lista. Hay muchas formas de validar y manejar en su caso esto en tiempo de ejecución, pero claro si tardamos media hora en que se ejecute `app.btn = []`, tarda media hora en aparecer el error...

Aquí es donde entran las anotaciones de tipo y los comprobadores como MyPy, si modificamos la declaración de `self.btn` añadiendo la correspondiente anotación de tipo:

```
self.btn: Button = Button()
```

al lanzar MyPy obtendremos nuestro correspondiente error de tipado sin tener que ejecutar el código:

```
$ python -m mypy test.py

test.py:13: error: Incompatible types in assignment
(expression has type "List[<nothing>]", variable has type "Button")
```

Otro ejemplo, una función que recibe una lista de enteros o floats y retorna la suma de sus elementos (Python >= 3.5):

```
from typing import List, Union

def suma(lista: List[Union[int, float]]) -> Union[int, float]:
    s =  sum(lista)
    return s

# Algunas llamadas a la función
suma([1, 2, 3])         # Correcta
suma((1, 2, 3))         # Incorrecta, se le pasa una tupla
suma([1.8, 4, 3])       # Correcta
suma([1.8, "hola", 3])  # Incorrecta, la lista contiene algo que no es int o float
```

Ejecutar el código anterior el intérprete solo nos muestra el esperable error al intentar concatenar floats con cadenas, error que se genera solo cuando se ejecuta dicha línea, no antes:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'

Pero MyPy va más allá sin ejecutar el código mostrándonos los dos errores:

```
$ python -m mypy test.py
test.py:9: error: Argument 1 to "suma" has incompatible type
"Tuple[int, int, int]"; expected "List[Union[int, float]]"

test.py:11: error: List item 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "float"
```

Todo esto es relativamente nuevo en Python y se está actualmente trabajando en ello, por ejemplo falta que muchas librerías de terceros implementen la comprobación para sus propios "tipos", por ejemplo imaginemos el caso anterior pero con un array de NumPy que debe contener `int8`. Aunque parezca que las anotaciones son algo superfluas añaden un gran potencial, no solo en lo mostrado, sino que permite por ejemplo la optimización del código en compiladores JIT lo cual conllevando una mejora en el rendimiento, una de las ventajas del tipado estático.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @FJSevilla. Tu explicación es simplemente superlativa. Me parece muy interesante y útil eso de los comprobadores. Voy a informarme mejor sobre **MyPy** porque si es como dices creo que puede ser la solución a estos indeseables tiempos de espera. Genial!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

#### La respuesta rápida es NO se puede.

Ya sé, te preguntas por que en el caso de `C/C++` el compilador detecta muchos errores antes de ejecutar realmente el código y el ejemplo que has dado es muy bueno. La respuesta de esto es la naturaleza no tipada de `Python`, es decir, la posibilidad que te da el lenguaje de no tener que declarar el tipo de cada variable a diferencia de otros con `C`, `C++` o `Java` entre otros. Pero.. ¿Que tiene que ver el tipado con tu pregunta?. Veamos un ejemplo sencillo:

Supongamos este código `C++`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MiClase {
  public:
    void click (void);
};

void MiClase::click (void) {
  cout << "Click!!";
}

int main () {
  MiClase objeto1;
  int objeto2;

  objeto1.click();

  // Esto es erróneo el objeto2 es un int, obviamente no tiene un metodo click()
  objeto2.click();
  return 0;
}
```

Esto se compila fácil y rápido, por ejemplo: `gcc test.cpp -lstdc++`, sin embargo, la compilación arrojará un error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:22:11: error: request for member ‘click’ in ‘objeto2’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
   objeto2.click();
           ^
```

Lo que ocurre es bastante evidente, `objeto2` es de un **tipo de dato** `int` que por supuesto no posee un método `click()` (siendo estrictos ni siquiera `int` es un objeto). Esta validación es relativamente fácil de implementar en tiempo de compilación, en el momento que hemos escrito `int objeto2;` el compilador "guarda" la referencia al nombre y al tipo, por lo que cada vez que vea la variable `objeto2` es trivial validar cualquier uso que hagamos de ella.

Ahora veamos un código bastante parecido al anterior en un lenguaje no tipado como `Python`.

```
class MiClase:
    def click (self):
        print("Click!!")

objeto1 = MiClase()
objeto1.click()

objeto1 = 1
# Esto fallará por que ahora objeto1 es un int
objeto1.click()
```

Esto fallará en tiempo de ejecución con la siguiente excepción:

```
Click!!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    objeto1.click()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Nota que se llego a ejecutar `objeto1.click()` no así la siguiente llamada ya que `objeto1` ha sido redefinido como un `int` con `objeto1 = 1`. Y nuevamente un `int` no posee un metódo `click()`. Para el compilador de un lenguaje no tipado no es nada sencillo saber que la segunda es inválida, la única forma que tiene es ejecutar el código y "ver que pasa". Este ejemplo es sencillo y podría parecerte evidente el error, sin embargo imaginate casos más complejos pero muy habituales: que la redefinición de `objeto1` dependa de la entrada de un usuario, la consulta a un api, la existencia de un determinado archivo o dato, etc. Podrás imaginarte entonces que la única forma que tiene Python para saber de que tipo es un objeto (y validarlo) es ejecutar el código.

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder @Patricio Moracho. Es una muy buena explicación y se entiende perfectamente. Mas que suficiente para satisfacer mi pregunta. Sin embargo, la explicación de FJSevilla también es extremadamente buena y elaborada. Ahora Me encuentro en un dilema, me encantaria poder aceptar las dos respuestas como validas.

Comment: @IvánRodríguez, contestar también es una oportunidad de aprender para los que respondemos, así que el agradecimiento es mutuo y el "premio" al menos para mí es justamente eso.